# What does the Millennium Falcon use for fuel?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

What does the Millennium Falcon use for fuel (and how big is the fuel tank)?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/YT-1300_light_freighter/Legends

Comment: It take me less than a minute to find the answer on wookipedia, and just a little more to catch the correct page of SW Millenium falcon's guide. I don't say it's complete trivia, but a little research could do the job.

Comment: @Kepotx - You might wish to note that the source in your answer is not part of the accepted canon. That book (along with all of the other pre-2014 guides) are considered to be "Legends" and subject to change without notice.

Comment: So ... not [liquid schwartz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvMiZCyA2xc), then?

Comment: The fuel is actually the tears of star wars fans who were upset with Lucas on whether Han shot first.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE!! Usually we have just one question per, well, question. I notice you have asked 3 questions here, including tank size and fuel cost. I would advise you to raise separate questions about those. Have fun!

Comment: @Kidburla - A decent answer can address all of these

Comment: "*What does the Millennium Falcon uses for fuel?*"  Plot.  It uses **plot** for fuel...

Comment: Tibanna gas liquidified, as most spaceships out there.

Comment: @Valorum your answer didn't mention about how much fuel costs. I see this as an unrelated question.

Comment: @Kidburla - Agreed. I've split it off as a new question...

Comment: Related questions - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180210/how-much-does-it-cost-to-refuel-the-millennium-falcon?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 27):

### Sublight Engines

According to the (canon) [*Force Awakens: Incredible Cross-Sections*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_Incredible_Cross-Sections), the Falcon uses

> ***liquid metal fuel***

to power its *sublight* engines. There's no indication *which* metal.

[image]

You can see the fuel tank on this earlier (and non-canon but still excellent) plan from [*Star Wars: Incredible Cross-Sections*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Incredible_Cross-Sections). Assuming it's hollow, the tank depicted appears to be around 3-4000 litres in volume.

[image]

---

### Hyperdrive Engines

The Hyperdrive engine is powered by ejecting

> ***Hypermatter particles***

The tanks are sufficiently large for them to cross half of the galaxy without refuelling.

Comment: In other words, it takes leaded

Comment: @Machavity - No wonder Han is so mercurial...

Comment: 3,000-4,000 liters is quite a lot of T-1000s, if you think about it.  Refueling must be pretty dangerous.  Kind of surprised they never showed that process in any of the films; could have made for a pretty epic action sequence, with the right director.

Comment: @TrevorPowell The issue is Star Wars frequently has the wrong director ...

Comment: @Azor-Ahai you didn't need to see Flash Gordon tank up his spaceship, and you don't need to see Han tank up the MF.

Comment: "The *liquid* fuel *sublimates* into a poisonous gas"... Somebody needs to be taught the meaning of *sublimation*.

Comment: @silvascientist Star Wars franchise != science fiction. The entire canon is science *fantasy*.

Comment: @Lexible It's simple terminology. Solids sublimate, liquids vaporize.

Comment: @Lexible Wait, the word you want to drop is *fiction*, not *science*?

Comment: @MishaRosnach To some people, fiction implies a consistent, well thought out world where fantasy  implies a hand-wavy 'anything goes' world. Personally I've seen fictional stories where the world makes no sense and fantasy stories that had systems and physics that were more sensible than our own universe seems to be, so I can't really agree to those definitions...

Comment: @MishaRosnach Yep. [Science *fantasy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_fantasy)

Comment: @JAB I agree. Likewise the atmosphere breathable by humans cannot be contained by "magnetic shields", orbital mechanics does not have a law that objects subject to decreasing forces slow and stop, human-audible sound does not travel through the interplanetary medium,  etc. etc. *ad nauseaum*. Star Wars is not science fiction... it is a Shakespearean-plot style family drama dressed up with fantasy blasters, fantasy space ships, fantasy space swords, etc.

Comment: @JAB I'd be careful with vaporize _(which can be solid or liquid -> gas)_, as the death star vaporizes planets.  I'd stick with evaporate _(which is more specific, only liquid -> gas)_

Answer (score 17):

**TLDR:** liquid metal fuel

As suggested by @JohnP, from the Wookieepedia, [YT-1300 light_freighter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/YT-1300_light_freighter/Legends) it is stated that the YT-1300 (the model of Millennium Falcon) use fuel cells powered by liquid metal fuel.

Another canon source is the [*Star Wars Millennium Falcon YT-1300 A 3-D Owner's Guide*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1603800611) written by [Ryder Windham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryder_Windham) himself:

Edit: as @Valorum says, those sources are not considered canon but rather "Legends" i.e. pre-2014 canon, subject to change.
[image: YT-1300 Propulsion]