# What kind of a ship could Obi-Wan and Luke have purchased for 10,000?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, tatooine

In ANH, Luke is shocked by Han's quote for the cost of passage on the *Millenium Falcon* to Alderaan.

> Ten thousand? We could almost buy our own ship for that!

What kind of a ship (if any) could have been rationally purchased for 10k on Tatooine at this point in time? Is Luke being facetious, or does he really have a point there that he and Obi-Wan might be able to make it on their own, without Han? What kind of a ship would have sold for about 10k on Tatooine around 0 BBY? A 100 year-old decrepit cargo tug with a leaking engine and a surly navicomputer? A nondescrepit, barebones shuttle that can at least complete the Kessel Run, albeit in at least 25 parsecs? A luxury pleasure yacht?

As @Valorum hinted at, I initially misremembered the quote. What I mean by the question is, what kind of ship was in the 10k-ish sort of purchase range?

Comment: A crappy one, I would assume.

Comment: @Valorum yes, but *how* crappy?

Comment: @RobertColumbia About 7, 7 crappy.

Answer (score 15):

Luke makes it pretty clear that 10,000 credits wouldn't be enough to buy a ship capable of getting them to Alderaan. It's only *almost* enough.

> “Ten thousand?” Luke gasped. “We could **almost buy our own ship** for
>   that!”

---

The [Star Wars RPG](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game_(first_edition)) (Edition 1, 1984) suggests that 10K will get you a chunky down-payment on a crappy used freighter.

[image]

---

You'd also need about a thousand credits for fuel and sundries

[How much does it cost to refuel the Millennium Falcon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180210/how-much-does-it-cost-to-refuel-the-millennium-falcon/180552#180552)

Comment: You'll need an extra 248 Spacebucks for tolls.

Answer (score 8):

I also went through my Star Wars RPG stuff (2nd edition) trying to find a starship with

- hyperdrive engine,
- price close to 10,000 Cr, and
- capacity to carry two passengers and two droids (and no questions asked).

The only one I could find was [*The Broken 'Spanner*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Broken_%27Spanner), a [Suwantek Systems TL-1800 freighter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TL-1800_freighter), in [Stock Ships sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stock_Ships). The used ship cost only 12,600 Cr, but it was most dilapidated.

> While it is by no means a superb craft, it at least travels from point
>   A to point B without too much difficulty.
>
> [...]
>
> The Broken 'Spanner is a maintenance nightmare. The engine requires
>   readjustment after every hyperspace jump. The astrogation computer
>   system is extremely glitchprone – due to the inherent design flaw and
>   poor maintenance
>
> [...]
>
> The port-side cargo pod capture mechanism has corroded so badly that
>   it will not function and must be completely replaced.

The same book states that a new TL-1800 transport cost 41,500 Cr. That said, a ship in poor condition was still worth around a third of the original price. That would make it possible to purchase at least two different kinds of ships for about 10 KCr:

- [XS-800 Light Freighter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/XS-800_light_freighter/Legends) (37,500 Cr as new)
- [Nesst Light Freighter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nestt-class_light_freighter) (30,000 Cr as new, from [Pirates & Privateers sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pirates_%26_Privateers))

If we can also assume that the price levels in general were lower in the Outer Rim, and on Tatooine, yes, it would have been possible for Luke to buy a simple freighter, but not in decent condition.

Comment: Plus fuel and supplies

Comment: On the plus side, an astromech of Artoo's skill would be able to manually operate the hyperdrive calculations

Comment: Aren't prices usually *higher* in remote locations?

Answer (score 1):

According to the canon reference book *Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know*, 10,000 Credits would almost get you a

> low-end starship

[image]

By all accounts, Luke was entirely correct.